# Request keeps on getting Error code: 400 - can someone please have a look on what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api

Spent a few hours trying to solve this but keep on getting 400 errors. I think my payload is incorrect but not sure what I need to do.

I've tried the same request in POSTMAN with great success, and also have tried different combinations on formatting my payload (body).

I've also tried the following:   `var body = {"document":{"type":"PLAIN_TEXT", "content":"This is great!!"}};`

```
 function main(){
        // Set the headers
      var headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ya29.GlyvBPhT4Y502Yo4NZ6sKI001AYlVU6om5ytXrzf2vjfEYERrsdMSBu-2ZkKir83jjj06-ewqYuBvvrx8mKfuTW1YjjlmtPmRdlK0I0Gjx',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'User-Agent': 'Untitled browser'
      }
      var uri = 'https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents'+encodeURI(':analyzeSentiment');
      var form = JSON.stringify({"document":{"type":"PLAIN_TEXT", "content":"This is great!!"}});
      // Configure the request
      var options = {
          url: uri,
          method: 'POST',
          headers: headers,
          form: form
      }

      // Start the request
      request(options, function (error, response, body) {
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
              // Print out the response body
              console.log(body)
          }
          else{
            console.log('Error code: '+response.statusCode)
          }
      })
    }

    main();
```

*Update* - this is how it works in POSTMAN[image]

Header is the same too: [image]

Comment: Well in the code block you posted the headers object has malformed syntax (looks like it's missing a closing `'`), is this the code you're using?

Comment: Sorry - took out some of my token, but yeah in my live code it's correct.

Comment: Can you double check if the request from POSTMAN has exact the same headers as your JS example?

Comment: You can also compare the two requests using developer tool in chrome and make sure they look exact the same.

Comment: Header looks correct too. :/

Comment: What happens if you remove the call to `JSON.stringify`? AFAICS you do not need to do that, according to the [documentation of the request module](https://github.com/request/request#applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-url-encoded-forms).

Comment: var body = {"document":{"type":"PLAIN_TEXT", "content":"This is great!!"}};

Will give the same error

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

Need to post as *body* rather than *form*